# Undocumented Java command line options?

Tags: java, jboss

On a server where I work is a JBoss instance, which has the following command line:

`/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms464m -Xmx464m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=20071 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jboss/lib/endorsed -classpath /opt/jboss/bin/run.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main -P /opt/jboss/server/default/site-deploy/example.com/boot-1.properties -c default`

I have a few questions:

**1.** I understand that the `-D` option sets the named property, e.g. `-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000` sets the property `sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval` to the value `3600000`.  What about `-D` options that have no equals sign, like `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`?  What is the value of `com.sun.management.jmxremote`?

**2.** I can't find ANY documentation explaining what the `-P` or `-c` options do.  Neither `java -version` or `man java` mentions them.  My guess is that `-P` means "load the properties from the specified file."  I have no idea what `-c` does.

**3.** The token `org.jboss.Main` doesn't seem to be part of the preceding `-classpath` option.  Is it the name of the class that Java is telling it to invoke, e.g. how `java Foo` would invoke a class called `Foo`?

Comment: `-P` and `-c` looks like program arguments, not options. Yes, `org.jboss.Main` seems to be the class with the main method.

Comment: Normally (for the `-D` question) I'd say see the docs, but [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) don't appear to say what it means without the `=`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms464m -Xmx464m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=20071 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jboss/lib/endorsed -classpath /opt/jboss/bin/run.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main -P /opt/jboss/server/default/site-deploy/example.com/boot-1.properties -c default
```

**1** System property without value means that system property is **present**, and value is empty string `""`

**2** those are the command line argument to jboss's Main class

**3** that class is coming from one of those jar, open `run.jar` and validate

Comment: So `-c default` means that the argument `default` is passed to the Main class?

Comment: yes there are 4 argument passed to Main class `["-P", "/opt/jboss/server/default/site-deploy/example.com/boot-1.properties", "-c" ,"default"]` this is the array representation

Comment: @dirtside: *Everything* after `org.jboss.Main` is arguments passed to `Main.main`.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Is #1 actually documented anywhere? I was pretty surprised to find [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) seemingly silent on `-D` without an `=`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah!  I get it now.  The -c and -P options are described in the Main.java file, here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/Main.java.html

Comment: @dirtside: Clarifying #3: That `org.jboss.Main` is the first unqualified argument to `java`, and it tells `java` which class's `main` method to run. That's why the things before it are arguments to the `java` command, and the things after it are arguments to `org.jboss.Main`.

Comment: Make sense.  Java command lines are always hard to read because of the eleventy billion options they always seem to need.  Isn't there some way to say "all the options you need are in some config file at /foo/bar/baz" so that the command line can look like this: `java -something configfile`?

Comment: @T.J. good question, i couldn't find the document stating this behavior clearly offhand, but certainly this is how it works

Comment: @T.J. For example this code demonstrate its intentional usage with http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/management/Agent.java

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Oh, I *believed* you... :-)

Comment: @dirtside: *"Isn't there some way to say..."* I guess that's what batch files are for. ;-) (And yeah, that would be handy.)

Answer (score 0):

The following link documents all of the options to the jboss run.sh script:

[Chapter 5. Starting and Stopping JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/start-stop.html)

```
usage: run.sh [options]
  -h, --help                  Show this help message
  -V, --version               Show version information
  --                          Stop processing options
  -D<name>[=<value>]          Set a system property
  -d, --bootdir=<dir>         Set the boot patch directory; Must be absolute or url
  -p, --patchdir=<dir>        Set the patch directory; Must be absolute or url
  -n, --netboot=<url>         Boot from net with the given url as base
  -c, --configuration=<name>  Set the server configuration name
  -B, --bootlib=<filename>    Add an extra library to the front bootclasspath
  -L, --library=<filename>    Add an extra library to the loaders classpath
  -C, --classpath=<url>       Add an extra url to the loaders classpath
  -P, --properties=<url>      Load system properties from the given url
  -b, --host=<host or ip>     Bind address for all JBoss services
  -g, --partition=<name>      HA Partition name (default=DefaultDomain)
  -u, --udp=<ip>              UDP multicast address
  -l, --log=<log4j|jdk>       Specify the logger plugin type
```